# What is the difference between calling dask.distrubuted.Executor and dask.distributed.Client

Tags: python, distributed, dask, dask-distributed

I have a question about the concurrent futures gist from the dask documentation: https://gist.github.com/mrocklin/ef9ccd29a6ec5f4de84d6192be95042a

When we instantiate an Executor, does that mean it instantiates a scheduler as well? The repr of the executor says

`<Client: scheduler='tcp://127.0.0.1:60329' processes=4 cores=4>`

So what is the difference between calling Client() and Executor()? The documentation seems to be very similar if not the same. In the concurrent futures examples some first instantiate a Client and then an Executor with the IP address of the Client.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are exactly the same.  Executor is an older name for Client.

Originally Dask used the term `Executor` to match the [concurrent.futures](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html) API.  However this term was confusing for Spark users, for which `Executor` was used for their worker equivalent.  We changed the term `Executor` to `Client` in 2016 and will eventually deprecate this term.